# L.A. vs NYC (punctuation)

Tags: punctuation

After researching the internet for a while now, I am still not sure whether it is true that one abbreviates Los Angeles by L.A. but New York City by NYC.

Is that true, if so, why the different punctuation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can sum it up by saying:  convention.

Neither of these is an "official" abbreviation.  You will see LA in print, and you will see N.Y.C. in print (in addition to the L.A. and NYC you spoke of in your question).

L.A. in common usage can actually refer to [The City of Los Angeles](http://www.lacity.org/index.htm), or Los Angeles County.  Of note, the official website shows multiple instances of LA instead of L.A.

New York City is not the official name of the city. It is [*The City of New York*](http://www1.nyc.gov).  But, common usage refers to it as New York City and hence NYC.  In recent years, the City has branded themselves with NYC on a lot of public programs and websites.

Add to this the fact that many of the official abbreviations are determined by the style manuals of various state and local authorities.  [See this example from New York State](http://www.courts.state.ny.us/reporter/new_styman.htm)